# group by query in sql server returns duplicates

Tags: sql-server

i have a problem in Sql server, Group by query which returns me one field of table twice (means duplicate). i don't know how to overcome this problem please.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[States_of_Path_SelectAll]
AS
    SELECT FromState
    FROM RawPaths
    GROUP BY FromState
```

Above is the query and it returns a `FromState` having value equal to `Close By` twice while other `FromState` are ok.

output of the query is :
     Meeting 
     CloseBy 
     Ignore 
     Follow 
     CloseBy

Comment: Try copying and pasting the output from the query into a text editor - if you  check the output closely, you will probably find additional space characters  in the apparently duplicated grouped value.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add an example of your RawPaths table content and another one with your desired query output

Comment: Actually i want exactly  one occurrence all the FromState. there are actually 4 (distinct) states but i am getting 5 states (i.e one is duplicate). Actually i want like this (Meeting,CloseBy,Ignore,Follow) but this query returns me like (Meeting,CloseBy,Ignore,CloseBy) table data given below

Comment: 1473  Meeting  1472 1472 1473 1431 1388
1472 CloseBy  1472 1473 1431 1388 1347
1347  Meeting  1305 1307 1267 1268 1269
1305  Meeting  1307 1267 1268 1269 1271
1307  Meeting  1267 1268 1269 1271 1313
1271 CloseBy  1313 1398 1440 1440 1440
1313  Meeting  1398 1440 1440 1440 1439
1398 CloseBy  1440 1440 1440 1439 1480
1440 CloseBy  1440 1440 1439 1480 1521
1440  Ignore  1440 1439 1480 1521 1561
1440  Ignore  1439 1480 1521 1561 1602

Comment: Sticking data in comments is not helpful. We can't make head or tails of it. Instead, please add the data to the question.

Comment: Try changing your select clause to be `SELECT FromState, LEN(FromState)` (etc) to see whether one of the FromState values is longer than it appears.

Comment: Yes one FromState (CloseBy) length is 7 while the other FromState(CloseBy) length is 8 . so how to overcome this please?

Comment: Mark Bannister, waiting for your kind response please.

Comment: See Brian Pressler's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have spaces in your data that don't belong.  You have a few options:

1)  Periodicatly clean up spaces that appear in your data.  You can use a statement like this:

```
update RawPaths
set FromState = ltrim(rtrim(FromState)
```

2)  Have your query remove the spaces:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(FromState)) as FromState
from RawPaths
group by ltrim(rtrim(FromState))
```

3)  Ensure only valid data can get into your table in the first place (best option).

You could create another table called States with an ID field and a description field.  Then change your FromState field to an integer and only allow valid states to be entered into the field though your interface and/or by using key constraints.

Comment: Thank you so much. i got 4 states now . using your provided solution